# Market manipulation of spot prices to profit from Bitcoin Futures

Tags: futures

Bitcoin futures are derivative instruments based on a closing Bitcoin price.  Is it possible for traders of Bitcoin futures to manipulate the closing Bitcoin price in order to profit from their Bitcoin futures position?

Comment: I have heard rumors that they are already doing this.